# XSLT grouping creation for sequence of elements with specfied condition

Tags: xslt, saxon, xslt-grouping, xsl-grouping

I'm new for xslt i need to transform the xml to xml with grouping

My input is here below in that i need to group introduction related information that all are have to group with box element, and i have list blocks as para with specified a attribute i have to group that as list block

```
<p style="Chap"></p>
<p style="ChapTitle"></p>
<p style="IntroHead">IntroHead</p>
<p style="IntroText">IntroText</p>
<p style="IntroText">IntroText</p>
<p style="IntroText">IntroText</p>
<p style="IntroLast">IntroLast</p>
<p style="Normal"></p>

<p style="Bullet">Bullet</p>
<p style="Bullet">Bullet</p>
<p style="Bullet">Bullet</p>
<p style="Bullet">Bullet</p>
<p style="Bullet">Bullet</p>
<p style="BulletLast">BulletLast</p>
<p style="Normal"></p>
<p style="Normal"></p>
<p style="Normal"></p>
<p style="Normal"></p>
<p style="Normal"></p>
<p style="Normal"></p>
<p style="Normal"></p>
<p style="Normal"></p>
```

My expected output is

```
<p style="Chap"></p>
<p style="ChapTitle"></p>
<box>
<title>IntroHead</title>
<list>
<li>IntroText</li>
<li>IntroText</li>
<li>IntroText</li>
<li>IntroLast</li>
</list>
</box>
<p style="Normal"></p>

<list style="bullet">
<li>Bullet</li>
<li>Bullet</li>
<li>Bullet</li>
<li>Bullet</li>
<li>Bullet</li>
<li>BulletLast</li>
</list>
<p style="Normal"></p>
<p style="Normal"></p>
<p style="Normal"></p>
<p style="Normal"></p>
<p style="Normal"></p>
<p style="Normal"></p>
<p style="Normal"></p>
<p style="Normal"></p>
```

Comment: 1. Please provide a clear statement of the rules you want to apply in order to group the input nodes. 2. Please add  your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: Also check the examples in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info on `xsl:for-each-group group-adjacent` and/or `group-ending-with`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xsl:for-each-group/@group-adjacent` to group paragraphs having the same `@style`. Within the body of the `xsl:for-each-group` do an `xsl:choose`: if `current-grouping-key()` is `Introtext` or `bullet`, wrap the group in a `list` element, otherwise copy it unchanged.

Comment: Somehow the `<p style="BulletLast">BulletLast</p>` and `<p style="IntroLast">IntroLast</p>` seem to part of the same group as `<p style="Bullet">Bullet</p>` or `<p style="IntroText">IntroText</p>`.